# Can Thunderbird indicate whether a sender is in the address book?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Does anyone know a feature or addon that allows Thunderbird to show whether a sender is in your address book or not? Either in the message list, or when viewing an email.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **contact** button in the **Quick Filter** toolbar. It will help the your browser window to show the messages only from the users who are in your address book. This may help you detect you whether the sender is in your address book or not. To let the browser show the messages from all the users click the same button again. So simple. Cheers! If you need more help, look into [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/quick-filter-toolbar).